# Storing and streaming mpeg4

Tags: android, video, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, streaming

My app needs to store mpg4 files on a server and be able to quickly grab them and stream them via the MediaPlayer. I have been using AWS S3 to store them after recording from my app but when I go ahead and grab them to stream them through the MediaPlayer it is sometimes fast but often slow. I was just hoping for a little guidance on the best approach to this. The videos need to be streamed back rather fast but S3 seems to be a bit slow and can be costly. What are the alternatives or best solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3's key selling point is high availability storage, rather than speed of access, especially if you need to access the content in many different geographic locations.

For reliable low latency distribution of video (i.e. minimum stops for buffering) you want a Content Distribution Network solution (CDN). In very simple terms, this creates cached copies of your content at the edge of the network so it can be accessed quickly.

Amazon's CDN solution is Cloudfront and it is designed to integrate with content stored on S3. The link below gives a good walkthrough of setting up Cloudfront for some S3 content. Note it does have a cost so you will need to check it meets your budget (other CDN's are available - they are all similar in concept):

- http://www.shootingbusiness.com/amazon-video-streaming-slow/

If you needs are small and localised, and you can test and confirm that performance is ok, you may be ok to simply host the Video on EC2/ECB, with a backup on S3 in case of issues. Again, you probably would need to run the different scenarios through the Amazon price calculator to decide the best approach for your needs.

I have never seen performance issues with this EC2/ECB approach for a small user base, certainly for users in the same general geographic area as the AWS availability zone, but it does not necessarily scale well, especially with a more distributed user base.